# How to Generate Embeddable Widgets, and Return PartialView, JS & CSS as JSONP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, widget, jsonp

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306122/embeddable-widgets-using-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc) which is a great starting point towards creating embedded widgets that enable showing dynamic content on remote sites (i.e. a different domain).

One problem I'm having is with the following code:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return new JsonpResult
    {
        Data = new { Widget = "some partial html for the widget" }
    };
}
```

It says `Widget = "some partial html for the widget"` but this doesn't really mean anything to me. I assume that `Widget` would contain the HTML representing what the user wants to see on the screen, but How do I get the contents of my Partial View into `Widget`?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to this issue exists here:

[How to Render Partial View into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string/2544150#2544150)