# Issue returning 'PartialView' inside JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, partial-views

I have a partial that I am reloading after an Ajax call. The following code works:

```
public PartialViewResult AddPreferredPosition(string playerID, int positionID)
    {
            playerService.AddPlayerPreferredPosition(Guid.Parse(playerID), positionID);

            PreferredPositionsModel model = new PreferredPositionsModel();
            model.PreferredPositions = playerService.GetPlayerPreferredPositions(Guid.Parse(playerID));
            model.Positions = playerService.GetPositions();
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Player/Partials/PreferredPositions.cshtml", model);
    }
```

along with:

```
var params = {};
    params.playerID = $('#PlayerID').val();
    params.positionID = $("select[name='ddlPositionID'] option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Admin/Player/AddPreferredPosition',
        data: params,
        success: function (data) {
                $('#PreferredPositions').html(data);
        }
    });
```

I want to alter it slightly to manage my error handling further to something like this:

```
public ActionResult AddPreferredPosition(string playerID, int positionID)
    {
        try
        {
            playerService.AddPlayerPreferredPosition(Guid.Parse(playerID), positionID);

            PreferredPositionsModel model = new PreferredPositionsModel();
            model.PreferredPositions = playerService.GetPlayerPreferredPositions(Guid.Parse(playerID));
            model.Positions = playerService.GetPositions();

            return Json(new
            {
                Success = true,
                HTML = PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Player/Partials/PreferredPositions.cshtml", model)
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                Success = false,
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message,
                InnerException = (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ""),
                ex.StackTrace
            });
        }
    }
```

with:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Admin/Player/AddPreferredPosition',
        data: params,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
                $('#PreferredPositions').html(data.HTML);
            } else {
                alert(data.ErrorMessage);
                console.log(data.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    });
```

However, when I do this then `data.HTML` is not the compiled partial view's HTML, as it is in the working example.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Correct your Code in this Section.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Admin/Player/AddPreferredPosition',
    data: params,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            $('#PreferredPositions').html(data.HTML);
        } else {
            alert(data.ErrorMessage);
            console.log(data.StackTrace);
        }
    }
});
```

As you are returning `JSON`, you'll have to parse that Data from Json.
Else you won't be able to access that data directly by

```
data.HTML
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the original code, the `PartialView` is returned which then gets rendered by Razor to HTML. In the modified version you return the same thing but inside an object, and therefore it stays unrendered.

In fact rendering *does* take place, but it is JSON rendering, which does not 'automagically' lead to HTML rendering of the PartialView object that it contains. See **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2537741/1220550)** or **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5532345/1220550)** for possible solutions to achieve that.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying. Is there a way around that so that I can have the view rendered by Razor, but still have some error handling in my ajax call?

Comment: I added some links into the answer, I think they should help you achieve that.