# ASP MVC 3 render partial to string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderpartial

I'm trying to render an .ascx file to a string using this method

[How to Render Partial View into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string)

And it works fine. But if the .ascx file that I'm trying to render contains another .ascx file  rendered like so

```
<%= Html.Partial("Picture/ProfilePicture", pictureThumb)%>
```

I get the exception

```
View cannot be null
```

when rendering ProfilePicture.ascx

Comment: is picturethumb null by any chance?

Comment: no :), the IView parameter of the method that actually renders the .ascx file is null. This only fails when I try to render the parent .ascx file as string, otherwise it works fine