# How to email an invoice in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code to send a mail, but I want to send my invoice view in mail.

```
MessageDetails _msg = new MessageDetails();
_msg.Body = "Your Booking is Accepted";
string userId = null;
if (booking.BookedFor != "0")
{ 
    userId = booking.BookedFor;
}
else
{
    userId = booking.UserId;
}
var code = userName.GetUserNameById(Convert.ToInt16(userId));
_msg.Destination = new string[] { code };
_msg.Subject = "Booking Confirmed";
_service.SendEmail(_msg);
```

How to send a Invoice View through mail?

Comment: Generally, you need to assign the content of your message to _msg.Body property. What concretely is the "invoice view" you mentioned? Is it a raw text or html or a file? Or is it an mvc view?

Comment: Its only a mvc view

Comment: I want to send Invoice through _msg.Body,but how i pass the view??

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not send view through email. You need to convert the view to raw html then parse the html at messagebody.

Comment: actually you can its a hard way

Comment: i want to attach my rajor view in mail,is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Razor views - I think something like this can help you achieve your goal:

```
//create a view model 
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Relative/Path/To/YourView.cshtml");
var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
var result = Razor.Parse(fileContent, yourViewModel);
_msg.Body = result;
```

Comment: i want to attach my rajor view in mail,is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameters to the razor view and generate dynamic content very easily

This method is used by me to convert Razor view to HTML

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38322783/5237614

Its easy to generate and style html, very easy to test also

Comment: i want to attach my rajor view in mail,is there any way to do that?

Comment: @aparnasharma both are same, you get html at the last, you can send it as mail