# Passing Jquery variable to MVC Controller using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a variable in Jquery which I want to pass to one of the parameters in my Controller method.

This is my AJAX code:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".getDetails", function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        alert(val);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetDetails',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                partsId: val
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#detailsPlace').html(result);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            });
    })
</script>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int partsId)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

All I want to do is pass the val variable to my partsId parameter, the code that I am currently using keeps returning the partsId parameter as null whenever I debug it.

Comment: Just remove `contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont use json format?

```
$(document).on("click", ".getDetails", function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetDetails',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"partsId": val}),
        dataType: 'json'
    })
        .success(function (result) {
            $('#detailsPlace').html(result);
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        });
})
```

Comment: I need to return a partial view so I cant can I? I just tried it and it hit the error not the success

Comment: which partial you want to return ?

Comment: my controller is returning a html partial view?

Comment: see this for returning partial :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2539577/6350942

Comment: why do I need to do that when that part is working all I want to do is pass the variable over?

Comment: variable didnt pass yet?

Comment: my questions says I want to pass the val variable over to my controller thats it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127492/discussion-between-ali7091-and-luke-rayner).