# How to get rendered PartialView from ViewEngineResult

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to render a PartialView in my Controller. I need the HTML of the PartialView to be specific. I'm using [this code](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/getting-html-for-a-viewresult-in-asp-net-core) in order to get the HTML. The problem that I have right now is that I don't get the rendered PartialView but the whole View. I need the HTML of the rendered PartialView for an email. The ViewEngineResult doesn't show any possible way of getting the PartialView.

Is there any way of getting the HTML of a PartialView?

This is how I'm using the code from the post

```
            var partialView = PartialView("Index", viewModel);
            var html = partialView.ToHtml(HttpContext);
```

I had to change the ViewResult parameter in the ToHtml() Method.

Before

```
    public static string ToHtml(this ViewResult result, HttpContext httpContext)
```

After

```
    public static string ToHtml(this PartialViewResult result, HttpContext httpContext)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the code of how you are calling the `ToHtml()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Render Partial View into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate question. You might find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string

Comment: @Rahatur I tried every single answer in this post and it didn't help me. The reason for this is the version of the MVC framework. I'm currently using asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

return the view you want.

for example purpose, suppose you want this "InvalidConfirmToken" view to return from controller, write:

```
return View("InvalidConfirmToken");
```

and remove partial rendering from layout.cshtml:

```
Html.RenderPartial("_ConfirmEmailAlert"); //remove this line
```

or put this line at the top of the _ConfirmEmailAlert.cstml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging I found [this](https://www.surinderbhomra.com/Blog/2018/09/02/ASPNET-Core-Render-Partial-View-To-String-Outside-Controller-Context). Works perfectly now