# Am I able to refresh a partial view without refreshing the main view and pass in a parameter at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to refresh my partial views whenever my dropdown closes and pass the string from the dropdown into those views (when necessary, some do not require the string to be input).  However, I am not sure how to be able to get the javascript and razor to work with each other.

I have tried updating the Model.ProdLine.Id value whenever the DropDown closes but I read that the model essentially disappears after the page is created so that is not a viable option.  Next I tried to have a JS function pass the parameter into the method but because they are rendered client side, they never get re-rendered to update the changes, without resetting the main view and essentially being reset to the default.

```
<script>
function OnClose() {
    var chart = $("#safetyIncident-chart").data("kendoChart");
    //Just refresh MonthlyPSAGauge and pass in the current string to the method.
    chart.dataSource.read();
}
function DropDownValue() {
    var value = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    return { selectProductionLine: value };
}
</script>
```

I used KendoUI TabStrip for this but each content method can be considered its own partial view so that should not effect anything.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("display-tabstrip")
        .Animation(animation =>
            animation.Open(effect =>
                effect.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
.Items(tabstrip =>
{
tabstrip.Add().Text("Safety")
.Selected(true)
.Content(@<text>
        @Html.Action("MonthlySafetyChart", "Display")
    </text>);
tabstrip.Add().Text("PSA")
    .Content(@<text>
        @Html.Action("MonthlyPSAGauge", "Display", new { selectProductionLine = Model.ProdLine.Id})
    </text>);
})
)
```

What I want is to be able to select a different value from the production line and have the partial views update to match that value, but I cannot have the whole page refresh only the partial views.
Feel free to ask for clarification and I will try my best!

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string ?  In short, make an ajax call to the server.  Server renders the partial view in the controller action and returns HTML in the response.  Use the response HTML to populate a content element.

Comment: I have not tried that.  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Chadnt could you provide an example of this? What do you mean by populate content element? So you would have a JS function that makes the AJAX call to grab a rendered partial view and then what would you do from there?