# Returning partial view with a boolean value

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an action method which returns a partial view to an ajax call. Whenever the partial view is received in success block of the ajax call, I am rendering it like this;

```
 success: function (res) {
                $('#competitorTables').html(res);
            }
```

But the action method has a condition within itself and it can result either true or false. I want to be able to return this boolean value with my `return PartialView()`block and then I want to be able to process it in my ajax call like this;

```
 success: function (res, isConditionSatisfied) {
                if(isConditionSatisfied){
                   $('#competitorTables').html(res);
                   alert('Condition satisfied');
                }else{
                   $('#competitorTables').html(res);
                   alert('Condition did not satisfied');
                }
            }
```

Is there a way that I can manage it? Thanks in advance.

**Addition**: Here is how I return from my action method;

```
return PartialView("_CompetitorTables", model);
```

Comment: you can not get partial view as well as data, because if you return something from controller you will get it inside partial view not in your ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that i suggest is creating a view-model that contains your Model + Your Condition.

Just Like this :

```
public class TestViewModel
{
   public Model model {get;set;}
   public bool condition {get;set;}
}
```

And in your controller :

```
var viewModel = new TestViewModel();
viewModel.condition = true;
return PartialView("_CompetitorTables", viewModel);
```

Comment: And how do I access the `viewModel.condition` from my ajax call?

Comment: @OzanYurtsever You can just get the rendered cshtml result from ajax call so you should do the bussineses in your partial view file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get value with partial view. The only solution you can do is to create a view model like following and saving partial view response in string and return that view model from your action. Then your code be like :

```
public class Model
{
  public string PartialViewResponce {get;set;}
  public bool condition {get;set;}
}

success: function (res) {
            if(res.Condition){
               $('#competitorTables').html(res.PartialViewResponce);
               alert('Condition satisfied');
            }else{
               $('#competitorTables').html(res.PartialViewResponce);
               alert('Condition did not satisfied');
            }
        }
```

you can view following link to convert partial view to string:
[Partial View to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do a similar thing; make an ajax call and render a partial view as well as return a decimal value to be used for another purpose.

Here's how approached the problem.

- I added the value I needed to the partial view model
- I created a hidden input somewhere in the partial view to hold this value
- Then I made my ajax call and on success, I render the partial view and also used jQuery to fetch the value of that hidden field and voila!