# Enable/Disable controls on a razor web page using Asp .Net 7 extension methods

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am rather new to Razor development. I want to set the disabled status of an input field based on a condition. So far, I have implemented the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase"
    asp-for="CustInfo.ORG_ID" 
    disabled="@(Model.RecMode == (short)RecModeId.Update ? "disabled" : null)" />
```

I want to improve the above implementation by doing something like the article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/670129/Enable-Disable-controls-on-a-web-page-using-MVC-Ra

I have:

```
namespace Demo.AppExtensions
{
    public static class DisableHtmlControlExtension
    {
        public static IHtmlContent DisableIf(this HtmlString htmlString, Func<bool> expression)
        {
            if (expression.Invoke())
            {
                var html = htmlString.ToString();
                const string disabled = "\"disabled\"";
                html = html.Insert(html.IndexOf(">",
                  StringComparison.Ordinal), " disabled= " + disabled);
                return new HtmlString(html);
            }

            return htmlString;
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to use it in a razor page, I have this error:

[image]

It seems like I didn't reference to the extension correctly. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperinputextensions.textboxfor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for `Html.TextBoxFor` in ASP.NET 7 returns `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent` instead of `MvcHtmlString` that's listed in the [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/670129/Enable-Disable-controls-on-a-web-page-using-MVC-Ra) in your post.

Updating the `DisableIf` extension method from `this HtmlString htmlString` to `this IHtmlContent htmlContent` is the first fix.

The second is changing `var html = htmlString.ToString();` to using `htmlContent.WriteTo()`.

After these changes the extension method works.

```
namespace Demo.AppExtensions
{
    public static class DisableHtmlControlExtension
    {
        public static IHtmlContent DisableIf(
            //this HtmlString htmlString, Func<bool> expression)
            this IHtmlContent htmlContent, Func<bool> expression)
        {
            if (expression.Invoke())
            {
                // var html = htmlString.ToString();
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/65155001
                StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                htmlContent.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
                string html = writer.ToString();

                const string disabled = "\"disabled\"";
                html = html.Insert(html.IndexOf(">",
                  StringComparison.Ordinal), " disabled= " + disabled);
                return new HtmlString(html);
            }

            return htmlContent;
        }
    }
}
```

The extension method in use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.CustInfo.ORG_ID, new { @class = "form-control text-uppercase" }).DisableIf(()=> Model.RecMode==(short)RecModeId.Update)
```

Comment: @RyanOng I'm glad the fixes worked. Even though the article is many years old, the purpose of the extension method is still effective today. I'll be using it too moving forward.