# ASP.NET MVC 2 JSONP with MVC Futures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, rest, cross-domain, jsonp

I´m using mvc futures 2 with WebApiEnabled for XML and JSON support. But due to cross domain issues with jQuery $.ajax I´m lookin in to JSONP.

Is there a simple way to extend futures rest function for JSONP or should I do something else.

Do anyone have some hints on this subject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST for ASP.NET MVC SDK contains a Word file explaining how you could extend it by adding a custom format:

> ASP .NET MVC provides capability to
> return HTML. MVC REST adds out of the
> box support to return the two most
> popular formats for programmatic
> access on the web: XML and JSON. In
> addition, you can also handle
> additional formats. This section shows
> how you can add support for a custom
> format such as Atom using the provided
> extensibility. The process involves
> creating a custom Format Handler, and
> registering it to handle requests,
> responses, or both. The steps specific
> to enabling custom formats are
> described below:
>
> 1. Create a custom format handler that may implement either or both of the
>    interfaces IRequestFormatHandler and
>    IResponseFormatHandler.
> 2. Register the custom format handler in global.asax in Application_Start

In the included `MovieApp` sample you will find an implementation for `AtomFormatHandler` which you could use as a base for adding the JSONP functionality. I've also written a [JsonpResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306122/embeddable-widgets-using-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc/2306157#2306157) which you may take a look at.